# Copy Person or Group column value to Task list using Approval Workflow in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-designer, task-list, approval, person

I have a Library in SharePoint Online, the Library has a Person or Group Column named Followers which stores multiple users. I need to move this information to the Task List using Approval Workflow in SharePoint Designer.

I have created a task list column(which is also a person or group) using SharePoint Designer by editing the Approval Workflow. Then by editing the single task workflow i set the value of the current item to the current item in the task list.

But it only copies single user and not multiple users.
Is there a way to copy the person or group column which has multiple users using Designer Workflow?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because your task list column is set to only allw single users.

Go to your task list and go into the list settings. Click on the Assigned To column and set the radio button to allow multiple users and then click OK.

Comment: Its already set to multiple users, but it doesnt work. If i push a single user, the user reflects in the task list. But if i push multiple users then its blank in the task list.